# Room @NonNull primary key and parcelable operations

Tags: android, android-room

Here is my entity :

```
@Entity(foreignKeys =
        @ForeignKey(entity = User.class,
                parentColumns = "user_Id",
                childColumns = "user_Id",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices = @Index(value = {"user_Id"})
)
public class AutoLogin implements Parcelable {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "token_Id")
    private String tokenId;
    @NonNull
    @TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expiration_date")
    private OffsetDateTime expirationDate;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_Id")
    private Long userId;

    public AutoLogin(@NonNull String tokenId, @NonNull OffsetDateTime expirationDate,
                     @NonNull Long userId) {
        this.tokenId = tokenId;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    protected AutoLogin(Parcel in) {
        tokenId = in.readString();
        expirationDate = (java.time.OffsetDateTime) in.readSerializable();
        userId = in.readLong();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(tokenId);
        dest.writeSerializable(expirationDate);
        dest.writeLong(userId);
    }
```

The problem is that the operations tokenId = in.readString() and expirationDate = (java.time.OffsetDateTime) in.readSerializable() are highlighted because they might evaluate to null a field annotated @NonNull (which I'm forced to do for the tokenId as it's a primary key.

How can I correctly solve this ?